# How to properly store objects that reference eachother? ( circular structure )

Tags: javascript, json, object

if I had something like

```
let a = {};
let b = {pointingTo: a},
a.pointingTo = b
```

then is it possible to store this someway in a .json file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No exactly because you can't convert circular structure to JSON strings

but here's something you can do

```
let a = {a:1};
let b = {pointingTo: a,b:2};
a.pointingTo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b));
```

the output should be
`{"a":1,"pointingTo":{"pointingTo":{"a":1},"b":2}}`
then you can stringify and save it in JSON file

using node.js

```
require('fs').writeFileSync('file.json', JSON.stringify(a));
```

using browser

```
function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

download('file.json', JSON.stringify(a))
```

P.S:
to indent, all you need to do is `JSON.stringify(a, null, 2)`

Answer (score -1):

If this javascript is client side then you would have to store it in local storage, if its server side javascript I don't see why it wouldn't be possible. Its basically a very simplified version of MongoDB.